# How to run Liquibase on command line with Custom Change java class?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I am trying to run my liquibase update from the command line. However, I have a customChange in my changelog file, i.e. a Java file that implements liquibase.change.custom.CustomChange. The update is successful when running via Spring. However, when I try to apply the update via command line using

```
liquibase --changeLogFile=<my_changelog_file> --username=<my_user> --password=<my_password> --url=<my_url> --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --classpath='<path_to>/postgresql-42.2.8.jar:<absolute_path_to_my_jar.jar>' update
```

I am getting this error:

> Liquibase Community 3.8.6 by Datical
> Unexpected error running Liquibase: liquibase.parser.core.ParsedNodeException: liquibase.exception.CustomChangeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.<my_company>.platform.changeset.EncryptPasswordsChangeset

I have obscured any real values I am passing in for security reasons. Anyone know how to let liquibase find this file? I tried creating a jar with just the necessary files and adding that jar to the classpath, but that doesn't seem to work as the jar does not contain any main classes.

Running

```
jar tf <my_jar.jar>
```

results in:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/<my_company>/platform/changeset/EncryptPasswordsChangeset.java
com/<my_company>/platform/security/PasswordEncryptUtil.java
com/<my_company>/platform/encrypt/SymmetricCipher.java
```

Comment: You need to add your .jar file in the `--classpath` option

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip. Will update the OP to include more info.

Answer (score 0):

My jar was not formed properly. Should be building it with compiled .class files, not .java files.